# Finding prime factorization of a number using exponential notation

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that finds the prime factors for a number and print them

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
void primeFactors(int num);
int main()
{
    int num =0;
    cout<<"plese input a positive integer: "; cin>>num;
    primeFactors(num);
    return 0;
}

void primeFactors(int num)
{
    int fac=2;
    while (num>1)
    {
        if (num%fac == 0)
        {
            cout<<fac<<" ";
            num=num/fac;
        }
        else
        {
            fac++;
        }
    }
}
```

Example for console output:

**please input a positive integer: 2700**

**2 2 3 3 3 5 5**

I want to get an exponential notation for the output, for example: 2^2 x 3^3 x 5^2

Any ideas how can I achieve that? thanks

Comment: What have you tried? One brutish thing that you can do is to store prime factors `1,2,3,5,7,11,...N` into a vector, initialize it to zero, and then each time your algorithm finds one of those factors, increment the corresponding index in said vector. That way, you can print exactly what you want. But of course, this is very inelegant. Nevertheless, you really should provide your own thoughts/efforts if you want people to answer your question.

Comment: well, I'm complete beginner.. still not good at translating things to C++ code, I still don't know what vector in C++ is, but I will try to learn something about it

Comment: Reasonably straightforward solution: Step 1: keep track of the last factor you found. Step 2: keep track of how many times you found it. Step 3: delay printing until you know what to print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
void primeFactors(int num)
{
    int fac = 2;
    while (num > 1)
    {
        if (num % fac == 0)
        {
            cout << fac << "^"; //print the base first
            num /= fac;
            int pow = 1;
            while (num % fac == 0) //get the power of current base
            {
                num /= fac;
                pow++;
            }
            cout << pow; //print out the power, now we have fac^pow printed

            //if not the last factor, print a multiplication symbol
            if (num != 1)
                cout << " x ";
        }
        else
        {
            fac++;
        }
    }
}
```